# error found when we install npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6TEw.png)

I don't know why these error come when we simply write command create-react-app so please solve this error I want to made my project as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

Can we also have your code?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps and see.

1. Install Node (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. npm i -g
   create-react-app
3. create-react-app your-app-name

Answer (score 0):

Follow Steps: -

1. Install Node.js in your machine (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. create folder with your project name
3. Right click on folder open VS-CODE
4. open VS-Code's terminal
5. cd projectname
6. `npx create-react-app .`